# What did Hisoka do in the Hunter Exam?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In the first Hunter Exam of the series (Hisoka's second), [he](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Hisoka) was introduced into the series removing another applicant's arms from his body for bumping into him and not apologizing.

[image: hisoka's intro]

What did he actually do? We know Hisoka's abilities are Bungee Gum and Texture Surprise, but they don't explain how the arms are converting into flower petals as seen above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I highly guess they made that up to convert this scene into a less violent type for the younger-age audience. In the actual manga chapter 5, this was what it looked like:

[image: Hunter x Hunter Chapter 5]

You can see that the arm is chopped off but with no flower petals whatsoever and judging by the angle, the blood ought to be seen. They probably did not want to reveal that part and instead took it from the side angle by "magically" making the arm disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To merge the censorship and canon together, I think Hisoka used his cards and his super speedy hands to sashimi the guy's arms into petal-shaped flesh flakes, and that is why they are red!

For the fake Hisoka made from smoke that Gon whacks with his fishing pole; I say Hisoka made the shape by using Bungee Gum to hold smoke/steam together and covered it in texture surprise to look like himself.

If we believe it hard enough, it is true!