# Is it ever stated who the disappearing applicant was?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In episode 3 of *Hunter x Hunter*, Beans welcomes Gon as the 405th applicant to the exam. Later, Satotz states that there will be 404 participants in Phase One.

[image: Beans presents badge #405]
[image: "All 404 applicants will participate in Phase One."]

We know that [Hisoka... uh... disarmed one of the applicants](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/8404/274), however the "all 404" wording is still suspicious to me. (The "404" is not a translation error; however, the "All 404" may be.)

Was Satotz referring to the "disarmed" applicant, did he make a mistake in his headcount, or is there something else in play that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

405 entered the test. 1 was injured. So the 404 was correct. The hunter test is one of survival and cunning etc. the one Hisoka "Disarmed" could not continue with both arms gone.

Essentially he failed the test when he bumped into Hisoka and not apologizing. Perhaps if he had sensed his surroundings a little better, like a real hunter, the 404 would have been a 405.